# SVG background image stretched

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

here I added a background image to SVG but the image is stretching I had tried `preserveAspectRatio="none"` still image is stretched. I want a complete image that should be visible.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1013.269px" height="558.944px" viewBox="453.365 271.056 1013.269 558.944" preserveAspectRatio="none" enable-background="new 453.365 271.056 1013.269 558.944"
  xml:space="preserve">
       <g>
        <defs>
            <pattern id="img1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
            <image height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0"  href="https://i.ibb.co/wKNKdYH/bg.jpg" />
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#img1)" d="M521.695,539.785c-8.101,14.076-15.49,28.521-22.165,43.27c28.415,10.424,48.69,37.716,48.69,69.745
            c0,41.018-33.251,74.268-74.268,74.268c-5.151,0-10.179-0.526-15.035-1.524c-2.411,18.347-3.823,36.865-4.211,55.47h309.221
            c1.642-30.516,10.37-60.22,25.465-86.674L521.695,539.785z"/>
        </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: You want something other than none for preserveAspectRatio

Comment: @ Robert Longson How can I achieve that the image `cover` complete path. I'm a newbie to SVG. Can you point me in the right direction what I'm missing here.

Comment: Seems you're on the right lines except for the preserveAspectRatio value.

Comment: @ Robert Longson You mean I have to remove preserveAspectRatio value? if I removed also getting the same output.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio